# Creating Ellipse in WGS84 with metric parameters

Tags: postgis, ellipse

I have points in WGS84 (x,y), radiuses in meters (rx, ry), rotation angle in degrees. I would like to create a new WGS84 geometry.

I've tried this but the major/minor distances seem to be off by a few hundred meters in some cases.

Ellipse (x,y,rx,ry,rotation,#of segments in 1/4 of ellipse)

```
SELECT
transform(
 translate(
  rotate(
   scale(
    buffer(
     transform(setsrid(makepoint(0,0),4326),3395),
     1,
   $6),
  $3,$4),
 $5),
x(transform(setsrid(makepoint($1,$2),4326),3395)),
y(transform(setsrid(makepoint($1,$2),4326),3395))),4326)
```

Comment: If the radii are geodesic-based or ground-based, using 3395, "World Mercator", is not the way to go. It doesn't look like a direct geodesic method is available, but just about any projected CRS that's designed for the data's location may give better results.

Comment: Thanks for responding.   GIS is not my specialty.  Are you saying that I can replace the 3395 with another "projected" CRS that is in the area of where my data is?  Thank you!  Would this be like 2163 if my data was in the US